# Error on postgres migration files creation for dotnet

Tags: .net, postgresql, dbcontext

I read book Ultimate ASP.NET Core Web API. And there is a code first database creation using DbContext and IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<>.

```
public class RepositoryContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<RepositoryContext> 
{ 
       public RepositoryContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) 
       { 
              var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder() 
                     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) 
                     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json") 
                     .Build(); 
 
              var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RepositoryContext>() 
        
       .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection")); 
 
              return new RepositoryContext(builder.Options); 
       } 
}
```

The code is working for creating migration files. But I need this for Postgres - not MS SQL. And next code is not going to create migaration files. It terminates with the error:  Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping..ctor(System.Stri
ng, System.Type, System.Nullable`1<System.Data.DbType>, Boolean, System.Nullable`1, Boolean, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.Nullable`1)'.' was thro
wn while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Repository;
using Npgsql;

namespace CompanyEmployees.ContextFactory;

public class RepositoryContextFactory: IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<RepositoryContext>
{
    public RepositoryContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RepositoryContext>()
            .UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresConnection"), 
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("CompanyEmployees"));

        return new RepositoryContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

More of that I don't understand - why Rider IDE shows using Npgsql; as unused namespace while I explicitly use method UseNpgsql()...
Please give some hint - ChatGPT is not into it. Long time - no idea what to fix.

In appsettings.json connection string is
"ConnectionStrings": {
"PostgresConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres; Database=CompanyEmployees"
}
Or without Database parameter - both doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... It appeared that I needed to downgrade both EntitityFramework.Core and Tools and Npgsql to major 7 version - due to .net version 7.0.

Though I still don't get - why Rider shows using Npgsql; as unused.

Answer (score 0):

```
For first one you need to install **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**
**dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**
or Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

-------------------------------------------------------------------

You need to get **Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL** from nuget package for second one.
**Install-Package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL**
or **dotnet add package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL**
```

Comment: And Actuallly you need to use  proper version of EF Core. If you use .net6 you should use version 6.*.* for EF Core